# Javascript - retrive a value by key, including nested object

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I am trying to write a function that will retrieve a value by key, including searching in nested objects.

Here is as far as I got:

```
function getByKey (obj, key) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
         return obj[key];
   }else{
      for(var prop in obj){
          if(typeof prop  == "object" && prop !== null){
             if(prop.hasOwnProperty(key)){
               return prop[key];
             }else{
               return iterate(prop, key);
             }
          }
     }
  }
```

}

If someone have this function ready and working or can fix my it will be great. If someone knows Underscore function that can do this it will be great.

Comment: typeof needs no brackets, `null` is an object, `iterate` is missing.

Comment: Are you trying to get all values that have this same key? If so call recursively function that goes deep in objects.

Comment: @Leolian - that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Nested objects might hold same keys for different values so which one are you interested in such as the first one, last one or all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive style to search for the property of an object.

```js
function getByKey(obj, key) {
    function iter(o) {
        if (o !== null && typeof o === 'object') {
            if (key in o) {
                value = o[key];
                return true;
            }
            return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
                return iter(o[k]);
            });
        }
    }

    var value;
    iter(obj);
    return value;
}

var o = { a: 1, b: { c: 3, d: 4, e: { f: 5, g: 6 } } }

console.log(getByKey(o, 'f')); // 5
console.log(getByKey(o, 'b')); // { c: ... }
console.log(getByKey(o, 'd')); // 4
console.log(getByKey(o, 'q')); // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the  following: https://jsfiddle.net/0yqu339t/4/

```
function getByKey(obj, key) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return obj[key];
      } else {
        for (var prop in obj) {
          if (typeof(obj[prop]) === "object") {
            return getByKey(obj[prop], key);
          }
        }
      }
    }


    var o = {
      a: 1,
      b: {
        c: 3,
        d: 4,
        e: {
          f: 5,
          g: 6
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(getByKey(o, 'f'));
    console.log(getByKey(o, 'b'));
    console.log(getByKey(o, 'd'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're passing a reference to the key only to the iteration function, but never reference the original object that was passed to it. You need to use `obj[prop]`, as follows:

```
function getByKey (obj, key) 
{
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) )
    {
        return obj[key];
    }
    else
    {
        for(var prop in obj)
        {
            if( typeof obj[prop] == "object")
            {
                if(obj[prop].hasOwnProperty(key))
                {
                    return obj[prop][key];
                }
                else
                {
                  return getByKey(obj[prop], key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/72s35cz3/)

Comment: Trying and posting the result. thank's for the edit, it was a long day (:

Comment: It gets error id you don't check that the object is not null, either then that, works great,

Answer (score 1):

For recursively you can try ( with little help from JQuery )

```
var haystack = $.map(obj, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
var values = []; //or {} depending your situation
var getValues = function( needle, haystack, array ){
    if( haystack[key]) !== 'undefined' ){
      array.push(haystack[key]);
    }else{
      for( var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++ ){
            getValues( needle , haystack[i], array );
      }
    }
}
getValues( 'key', haystack, values );
console.log(values);  //should be an array [ value1, value2, value3, value4, ... ]
//With all values that have this same searched key
```

I hope this helps